# React to a user selecting a value from a drop down

Tags: jquery, html, select

Is there a jQuery event that gets fired when a user selects a value from a drop down list?

I need to load the next part of a form based on the selection a user makes in the first drop down and would like to avoid a button press.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.change()` event is fired when someone selects a value from a list.

If you don't have a blank default value as the first option ('Select One'),
you'll need to explicitly trigger the .change event when the page loads to display whatever content for the first item.

Answer (score 1):

[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event for the `<select>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use plain old Javascript for this:

```
 <select onchange='callMyMethod()'>
```